# Vue.JS, Axios, CanvasJS - get data from API and populate / render a chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am new to `Vue.JS` and trying to have reactive data in my chart, one step at a time. This is my `Javascript`:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var chartParent = new Vue({
        el: '#chartContainer',
        data: function() {
            return {
                chart: null,
                tempData: null
            }
        },
        computed: {
            chartOptions() {
                return {
                    theme: "light2",
                    subtitles: [
                        {
                            text: "Performance",
                            fontStyle: "bold",
                            verticalAlign: "center",
                            dockInsidePlotArea: true
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Legend (On Hover)",
                            fontStyle: "bold",
                            verticalAlign: "bottom",
                            horizontalAlign: "right",
                            dockInsidePlotArea: true
                        }
                    ],
                    toolTip:{
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                    data: [
                        {
                            type: "doughnut",
                            indexLabel: "",
                            mousemove: this.donutChartMousemove,
                            showInLegend: false,
                            dataPoints: [
                                {
                                    "y": 90,
                                    "label": "Temp In Range",
                                    "color": "#218340",
                                    "legendLabel": "(Temp ≤ + 1°F)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "y": 5,
                                    "label": "Temp In Tolerance",
                                    "color": "#F7B731",
                                    "legendLabel": "(+ 1°F < Temp <= 2°F)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "y": 5,
                                    "label": "Temp Above Setpoint",
                                    "color": "#A62337",
                                    "legendLabel": "(Temp > + 2°F)"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            axios
                .get('/api/temps')
                .then((response) => { this.tempData = response.data })
                .catch((error)   => { console.log(error) })
            this.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", this.chartOptions);
            this.chart.render();
        },
        methods: {
            donutChartMousemove: function(e){
                this.chart.subtitles[0].set("text", e.dataPoint.label + " (" + e.dataPoint.y + "%)");
                this.chart.subtitles[0].set("fontColor", e.dataPoint.color);
                this.chart.subtitles[1].set("text", e.dataPoint.legendLabel);
                this.chart.subtitles[1].set("fontColor", e.dataPoint.color);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This is the `JSON` data at `/api/temps`:

```
{
  "Temps_agg": {
    "Avg_Dry_Bulb": 95,
    "Station1": {
      "TempInRange_Day": 92.7777777777778,
      "TempInTolerance_Day": 7.2222222222222,
      "TempAboveSetpoint_Day": 0
    },
    "Station2": {
      "TempInRange_Day": 83.22222222222227,
      "TempInTolerance_Day": 16.777777777777832,
      "TempAboveSetpoint_Day": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I want to pass the values in `Station1` to my chart like so (code segment from above):

```
                            dataPoints: [
                                {
                                    "y": this.tempData.Temps_agg.Station1.TempInRange_Day,
                                    "label": "Temp In Range",
                                    "color": "#218340",
                                    "legendLabel": "(Temp ≤ + 1°F)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "y": this.tempData.Temps_agg.Station1.TempInTol_Day,
                                    "label": "Temp In Tolerance",
                                    "color": "#F7B731",
                                    "legendLabel": "(+ 1°F < Temp <= 2°F)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "y": this.tempData.Temps_agg.Station1.TempAboveSetpoint_Day,
                                    "label": "Temp Above Setpoint",
                                    "color": "#A62337",
                                    "legendLabel": "(Temp > + 2°F)"
                                }
                            ]
```

When I do that, I get this error:

```
app.js:28150 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Temps_agg' of null"
//trim
app.js:29413 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Temps_agg' of null
//trim
```

If I print the `axios` response, I can see the `JSON` response in the console:

```js
            axios
                .get('/api/temps')
                .then((response) => { console.log(response.data) })
                .catch((error)   => { console.log(error) })
```

I suspect I'm causing a "race" condition?

Edit 1: Thank you @hmm for the direction. This is what worked for me:

```
            async created () {
                try {
                    let response = await axios.get('/api/temps');
                    this.chartData = response;
                    this.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", this.chartOptions);
                    this.chart.render();
                }catch(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            },
```

You'll notice I removed `mounted ()` and I now render the chart in `async created ()`.

Comment: Your computed property based on `tempData` is evaluated immediately when the component is mounted. At that time, `tempData` is null. You need to handle that case while waiting for the axios call to complete.

Comment: Also, in your `mounted` hook, you are initializing the chart after calling `axios.get`. That call is asynchronous. You should initialize the chart in the response handler or as another computed property. That way, when `tempData` is updated, `chartOptions` is updated and then `chart` is updated.

Comment: @hmm Thank you! Would you mind taking a look at Edit 1? It works, but it feels 'hacky'.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Edit 1 is a bit "hacky" in the sense that Vue will not wait for promises to resolve before continuing the component lifecycle. It may work, but it doesn't seem like Vue way to do things.

I don't know your use case, but it seems like you can keep this very simple.

```
data () {
  return {
    chart: null
  }
},
mounted () {
  axios.get('/api/temps')
    .then((response) => {
      let chartOptions = {
        ...
        data: response.data,
        ...
      }

      this.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", chartOptions);
      this.chart.render();
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
}
```